# SQL to query the structure of a stored procedure output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For good reasons, I need to rotate the wide results of stored procedures to rows instead.

Something like this:

```
Col1, Col2, Col3
----------------
1     2     3
```

Becomes:

```
DataName, DataValue
-------------------
Col1      1
Col2      2
Col3      3
```

The wide results are provided by a stored procedure. The stored procedure, at the time that it is being called, is unknown to me. Sort of like "go hit this table and find out what stored procedure to call, then call it". For that reason, I can't know what the results will be, in terms of structure -- it will provide some columns, of some data type(s).

Because I don't know the result structure, I can't insert it into a #tmp table to find out the structure - though if I knew the structure I would not need to go find out -- chicken, meet egg.

I could do the insert into #tmp in the unknown stored procedure, and then query tempdb for the structure, except that local scope of the #tmp table gets in my way.

Alternately, I could make it global scope ##tmp, but that carries security issues.

So, my question is:

1. Is there a way that I've never seen to query SQL to find out what it knows about the resulting structure of a stored procedure. OR, Failing that,
2. Could I do that with a table-valued function? That is, SQL can treat the function as a table, so can I query to find out it's known structure?

Comment: Have a look at [sys.sp_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).  `EXEC sys.sp_describe_first_result_set N'EXEC dbo.MyProc';`

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to solve?

Comment: That's fair. Problem I'm trying to solve is this: I have objects defined in the db that tell a ui what to draw. Something like: Go to DB to find out what this form should have on it? Formfield definition stuff like control type, option list source, tab order, etc.

Architect wants the data inline with it., 
Elementname, controltype, taborder, currentvalue, label
'firstname', 'text', 10, 'Joseph', 'First Name'
'lastname', 'text', 20, 'Mama', 'Last Name'

and so on. We've got the form defined, permissions and multilingual support wired. We've got the data for the form. Just need to match.

Comment: Seems a terrible database design - why not use the database correctly i.e. with a relational, known data structure. Or use XML/JSON if necessary.

Comment: There is also `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` which is a table valued function. But I agree the design sounds terrible.

Comment: This sounds like an implementation of the anti-pattern known as EAV or entity-attribute-value. It is fraught with issues, usability and performance being the top two things it crushes.

Comment: Worth reading Phil Factor's article on the One True Lookup Table https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/when-the-fever-is-over-and-ones-work-is-done/. Also are sure you always want to present all fields returned by the stored procedure to the user - any GDPR data, security/audit data?

Comment: Oh and if anyone thinks EAV is a great idea to create a data driven application it might be worth reading https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/ about how this simple decsion destroyed a company.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.